# Strange "TypeError: Object is not a function" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am trying to create a mixin using Styled Components which I later use to style multiple components. However, I get this error at run-time:

[image: type error style components with TS]

There is no compile or lint error. I am using:

- Typescript: 2.8.3
- react-scripts-ts: 2.15.1
- styled-components: 3.2.6
- React: 16.3.0

What's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I had some error, but since I was upgrade react to ^16.8.3 and degrade styled-components to 4.0.3 - all works fine.

Seems upgrade React quite enought to solve)

It usual way to fix "strange errors", degrade "broken" libs and upgrade system libs.